# How to solve Selector matches unknown element connection?

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery library called jQuery Connections https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections with Atlassian Connect Application https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/guides/introduction.html
jQuery Connection library works fine if I am using it from outside but when I am including it in my current project I keep getting "selector matches unknown element connection".
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a connection tag in HTML

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari That's why it's inside <script> tag.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle 'cause I don't understand how this library works

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari  you can have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/FP7Zy/1/

Comment: Cool! now tell me where did you add the library in the project?

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari library is laready there and uploaded from the main file. As you can see all the .connections are working. Only thing that is not working are slectors with colon.

Comment: try the `:first-child` instead of `:first` maybe it will work

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've injected language to the string literal. Place caret there, press Alt+Enter, choose "Uninject language"